# How to sort a tab delimited file with sort command?

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, gnu-sort

I have a data with the following format:

```
foo<tab>1.00<space>1.33<space>2.00<tab>3
```

Now I tried to sort the file based on the last field decreasingly.
I tried the following commands but it wasn't sorted as we expected.

```
$ sort -k3nr file.txt  # apparently this sort by space as delimiter

$ sort -t"\t" -k3nr file.txt
  sort: multi-character tab `\\t'

$ sort -t "`/bin/echo '\t'`" -k3,3nr file.txt
  sort: multi-character tab `\\t'
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 377, accepted):

Using *bash*, this will do the trick:

```
$ sort -t$'\t' -k3 -nr file.txt
```

Notice the dollar sign in front of the single-quoted string. You can read about
it in the [ANSI-C Quoting sections of the *bash* man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

Comment: [Use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/4970442) `'"'"'` to use it inside an alias.

Comment: can you show how to pass this delimeter to sort within an awk command?  as in `awk '{print $0 | "sort -nr" > "outfile" }' datafile`, except with an escaped tab delimeter sent to the sort command.

Comment: Use `-g` rather than `-n` if you want numeric sort. `-n` is broken.

Comment: Also works in `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)`

Comment: Sorry, I have the same issue on Windows, is there a solution for Windows too? Other than copying the tab character and pasting it

Comment: @JoeJobs depending on terminal you can try `ctrl+v` and then pressing `TAB` to insert a literal tab character

Comment: I am wondering why this correct answer is not placed at the top?

Answer (score 12):

By default the field delimiter is non-blank to blank transition so tab should work just fine.

However, the columns are indexed base 1 and base 0 so you probably want

```
sort -k4nr file.txt
```

to sort file.txt by column 4 numerically in reverse order. (Though the data in the question has even 5 fields so the last field would be index 5.)

Comment: This will only work if the number of space characters between the tab-separated fields is the same for all lines of input.

Comment: Bad hack that doesn't work generally for valid tsv files that contain spaces in fields. Don't use for production!

Answer (score 8):

You need to put an actual tab character after the -t\   and to do that in a shell you hit ctrl-v and then the tab character.  Most shells I've used support this mode of literal tab entry.

Beware, though, because copying and pasting from another place generally does not preserve tabs.

Comment: This is the best (most portable) answer. emacs also lets you do that in 'quoted insert' mode: `C-q <tab>` for instance. I think it's `^V` in nano as well.

Comment: cntrl-q in QTerminal talking to the shell.

Answer (score 4):

The $ solution didn't work for me.
However, By actually putting the tab character itself in the command did:
sort -t'' -k2

Comment: Use `<C-v><Tab>` in order to insert tab in case the tab key is used for auto-completion in your shell.

Comment: ANSI quoting `$'\t'` works in ksh, zsh, and bash.  Bourne shell doesn't support it.  See this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371873/201820

Answer (score 3):

I wanted a solution for Gnu sort on Windows, but none of the above solutions worked for me on the command line.

Using Lloyd's clue, the following batch file (.bat) worked for me.

Type the tab character within the double quotes.

```
C:\>cat foo.bat

sort -k3 -t"    " tabfile.txt
```

Comment: Yeah the trick here is putting it in a .bat file, otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem with sort in cygwin in a bash shell when using 'general-numeric-sort'.  If I specified `-t$'\t' -kFg`, where F is the field number, it didn't work, but when I specified both `-t$'\t'` and `-kF,Fg` (e.g `-k7,7g` for the 7th field) it did work. `-kF,Fg` without the `-t$'\t'` did not work.

Answer (score 2):

`sort -t "$(printf '\t')"` works for me

Comment: Smart, albeit also shell-specific.

Answer (score 1):

In general keeping data like this is not a great thing to do if you can avoid it, because people are always confusing tabs and spaces.

Solving your problem is very straightforward in a scripting language like Perl, Python or Ruby. Here's some example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $sort_field = 2;
my $split_regex = qr{\s+};

my @data;
push @data, "7 8\t 9";
push @data, "4 5\t 6";
push @data, "1 2\t 3";

my @sorted_data = 
    map  { $_->[1] }
    sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] }
    map  { [ ( split $split_regex, $_ )[$sort_field], $_ ] }
    @data;

print "unsorted\n";
print join "\n", @data, "\n";
print "sorted by $sort_field, lines split by $split_regex\n";
print join "\n", @sorted_data, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Lars Haugseth answer only worked from the command line for me where it gives this error if executed from a shell script:

sort: multi-character tab ‘$\t’

The solution if it's coded in a shell script if anyone's looking is

```
sort -t'    '
```

the tab character is in between the quote.

Comment: You are using the wrong value. It should be `$'\t'` not `'$\t'`.

Answer (score 0):

pipe it through something like `awk '{ print print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5 }'`.  This will change the spaces to tabs.

Comment: @MB: I need to keep the space intact.

Comment: There's undoubtably a cleaner way to do it, but nothing prevents you from piping it through awk, change the spaces to tabs, sorting the data, and then piping it through awk again, changing the tabs back into spaces.

Comment: This won't work if there is a mixture of tabs and spaces that you want to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it easier for yourself by only having tabs, replace the spaces with tabs:

```
tr " " "\t" < <file> | sort <options>
```

Comment: My tr does not read files, only streams XD. `usage: tr [-Ccsu] string1 string2`

Comment: `tr string1 string2 <some-file`.  Everything can read a file as long as it can read stdin.

Comment: There are a lot of cases in where spaces cannot be transformed into tabs, e.g. logs (dates, user agents), people or country names (one, two or more words)... Just tell sort what is the split char.