# Linux shell sort file according to the second column?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file like this:

```
FirstName, FamilyName, Address, PhoneNumber
```

How can I sort it by FamilyName?

Comment: which os and command processor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix Sort with Tab Delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

If this is UNIX:

```
sort -k 2 file.txt
```

You can use multiple `-k` flags to sort on more than one column. For example, to sort by family name then first name as a tie breaker:

```
sort -k 2,2 -k 1,1 file.txt
```

Relevant options from "man sort":

> #### -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>
> start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
>
> POS  is  F[.C][OPTS], where F is the field number and C the character position in the field.  OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options, which override global ordering options for that key.   If no key is given, use the entire line as the key.
>
> #### -t, --field-separator=SEP
>
> use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

Comment: Just be a little careful to use `--field-separator=','` if you might have a data entry operator type in values for "First name" like "Billy Bob" or whatever... spaces can easily get into your data if you don't guard against it, but commas are relatively unlikely.

Comment: There are very likely cases of commas in those fields, like "Smith, Jr." or "McDowell, Sr." or "Dr. John" or "New York, NY"

Comment: Note that if the columns are visually aligned, i.e. there is a non constant number of spaces between each fields, you must use the `-b` option. This is because `sort` is actually considering that the string to sort starts just after the comma, and not from the first letter of the column. Also, you may need to prefix the command with `LC_ALL=C`, to avoid any side effect due to the locale, which can happen even on a simple ASCII file.

Comment: @calandoa Thanks for the part on `-b` (`--ignore-leading-blanks`). To clarify a bit: `echo -e 'aa<SPACE>a\na<SPACE><SPACE>b' | sort -k2` gives `a<SPACE><SPACE>b` first (the second column starts after the first `non-blank to blank transition`, and `<SPACE><SPACE>b` is before `<SPACE>a`), but with `-b` it gives `aa<SPACE>a` as expected (`a` is before `b`).

Answer (score 12):

```
sort -nk2 file.txt
```

Accordingly you can change column number.

Answer (score 7):

To sort by second field only (thus where second fields match, those lines with matches remain in the order they are in the original without sorting on other fields) :

```
sort -k 2,2 -s orig_file > sorted_file
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, here is a sort method for showing which processes are using the most virt memory.

```
memstat | sort -k 1 -t':' -g -r | less
```

Sort options are set to first column, using : as column seperator, numeric sort and sort in reverse.