# I want to execute [ more /etc/domainips ] commands and the results should be sort by username

Tags: linux, sorting

Hello when i want to execute `more /etc/domainips` commands on my ssh, I want to get the results like = sort by username.

Hello when i execute `more /etc/domainips` commands on my ssh the result showed up like this

```
a.com: D-user
b.com: B-user
c.com: A-user
d.com: C-user
```

I want to get the results like this = sort by username.

```
c.com: A-user
b.com: B-user
d.com: C-user
a.com: D-user
```

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262650/linux-shell-sort-file-according-to-the-second-column) answer your question?

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438896/sorting-data-based-on-second-column-of-a-file)? Or any of the other umpteen dupes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pipe the result of `sort` to `more`:

```
sort -k 2 /etc/domainips | more
```