# Sorting data based on second column of a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file of 2 columns and `n` number of rows.

column1 contains `names` and column2 `age`.

I want to sort the content of this file in ascending order based on the `age` (in second column).

The result should display the `name` of the youngest person along with `name` and then second youngest person and so on...

Any suggestions for a one liner shell or bash script.

Comment: Superset: custom delimiter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter

Answer (score 461, accepted):

You can use the `key` option of the [`sort` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort), which takes a "field number", so if you wanted the second column:

```
sort -k2 -n yourfile
```

> `-n`, `--numeric-sort` compare according to string numerical value

For example:

```sh
$ cat ages.txt 
Bob 12
Jane 48
Mark 3
Tashi 54

$ sort -k2 -n ages.txt 
Mark 3
Bob 12
Jane 48
Tashi 54
```

Comment: also note that using `-h` instead of `-n` will sort human readable values like `2G` or `3K` as well as numbers separated with commas e.g. `1,234.5`

Comment: Faced issue with "wrong" ordering. Pay attention to man "***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set `LC_ALL=C` to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values." (for string match case without `-n`)

Comment: This doesn't consider spaces in the first column neither works if there are more columns after the second, since -k read until the line end. Supposing it is a TSV file a better solution is ```sort -t$'\t' -k2 -n FILE```

Comment: you might need to specify your delimiter using the -t option

Answer (score 117):

### Solution:

`sort -k 2 -n filename`

more verbosely written as:

`sort --key 2 --numeric-sort filename`

---

### Example:

```
$ cat filename
A 12
B 48
C 3

$ sort --key 2 --numeric-sort filename 
C 3
A 12
B 48
```

---

### Explanation:

- **-k *#*** - this argument specifies the first column that will be used to sort. (note that column here is defined as a whitespace delimited field; the argument `-k5` will sort starting with the fifth *field* in each line, not the fifth *character* in each line)
- **-n** - this option specifies a "numeric sort" meaning that column should be interpreted as a row of numbers, instead of text.

---

### More:

Other common options include:

- **-r** - this option reverses the sorting order. It can also be written as **--reverse**.
- **-i** - This option ignores non-printable characters. It can also be written as **--ignore-nonprinting**.
- **-b** - This option ignores leading blank spaces, which is handy as white spaces are used to determine the number of rows. It can also be written as **--ignore-leading-blanks**.
- **-f** - This option ignores letter case. "A"=="a". It can also be written as **--ignore-case**.
- **-t *[new separator]*** - This option makes the preprocessing use a operator other than space. It can also be written as **--field-separator**.

There are other options, but these are the most common and helpful ones, that I use often.

Comment: @Angelo This answer was presumably posted years after you've accepted an answer for this question, but have you considered it as the new accepted answer?

Comment: Option `-t` was real life saver!! when your columns have spaces and columns differ by a given character like `,` or a tab

Answer (score 22):

For tab separated values the code below can be used

```
sort -t$'\t' -k2 -n
```

-r can be used for getting data in descending order.
-n for numerical sort
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2] where k is column in file
For descending order below is the code

```
sort -t$'\t' -k2 -rn
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `sort`.

```
sort ... -k 2,2 ...
```

Comment: You also need to use -n to sort based on ages (numeric sort). Otherwise '11' will come before '2'.

Comment: @MattRyall i have similar requirement but my second column has alphabet its like users. and first column has some blank cells. i am able to sort the users properly but i wanted the blank cell should come at the end. this is how i do. Please help me if know the trick

(head -n 1 Users.csv && tail -n +2 Users.csv | sort -t ',' -k 2) > UsersNew.csv

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
$ sort -k2,2n <<<"$data"
```