# unix sort descending order

Tags: unix, sorting

I want to sort a tab limited file in descending order according to the 5th field of the records.

I tried

```
sort -r -k5n filename
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 57):

The presence of the `n` option attached to the `-k5` causes the global `-r` option to be ignored for that field. You have to specify both `n` and `r` at the same level (globally or locally).

```
sort -t $'\t' -k5,5rn
```

or

```
sort -rn -t $'\t' -k5,5
```

Answer (score 20):

If you only want to sort *only* on the 5th field then use `-k5,5`.

Also, use the  `-t` command line switch to specify the delimiter to `tab`. Try this:

```
sort  -k5,5 -r -n -t \t filename
```

or if the above doesn't work (with the `tab`) this:

```
sort  -k5,5 -r -n -t $'\t' filename
```

The [man page for sort](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sort) states:

> -t, --field-separator=SEP
>           use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

Finally, this SO question [Unix Sort with Tab Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

To list files based on size in asending order.

```
find ./ -size +1000M -exec ls -tlrh {} \; |awk -F" " '{print $5,$9}'  | sort -n\
```