# GNU Sort using TAB as field separator

Tags: sorting, csv

I am using GNU sort (from GnuWin32) on Windows. I renamed it to "sort1.exe".
The input text file has spaces and tabs but the fields are delimited by tabs.
I tried with:

```
sort1 -n -k2 -t "\t" file.txt
```

but it says: "sort1: multi-character tab '\t'

the text looks like

```
lazy dog<TAB>123
fox<TAB>1
white tail wolf<TAB>11
blue bear<TAB>7
```

and the output should be like

```
fox<TAB>1
blue bear<TAB>7
white tail wolf<TAB>11
lazy dog<TAB>123
```

I tried using the advice [in the other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter) but it doesn't work in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There's another alternative.  I'm not 100% sure this is Windows compatible but you can try this way to type in a TAB character:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> (release)
2. Press the <kbd>Tab</kbd>

So you'd type the following:

> sort1 -n -k2 -t "<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>" file.txt

You should see that a tab is inserted between the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this (in Windows a tab is '^t' rather than '\t'):

```
sort -n -k2 -t'^t' file.txt
```