# Sort command included in Cygwin launched by normal Windows promppt don't accept $ operator for tab character

Tags: windows, cygwin, command-line-interface

I have installed Cygwin on my machine and I would to know if there exist a way to use full power of sort command also with the normal DOS prompt.

I have read this question: [Unix Sort with Tab Delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter)
and the command to sort a tabbed file using the second column is:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 2 file.txt
```

If I launch the command inside the Cygwin environment it works like expected, if I launch it from the normal Windows prompt (I have renamed sort.exe into xsort.exe to avoid conflicting with native Windows sort command) it doesn't works, it not recognize the $ operator and it see \t like two distinct characters and operation fails.

Is it possible to make it working also from the DOS prompt?

Answer (score 2):

This is regulated by `PATH` environment variable.

Under DOS prompt run the following:

```
echo %PATH%
```

You will see the path `C:\cygwin\bin` after `c:\Windows\system32`.

This means that Windows's `sort.exe` will be used for command `sort`.

You will need to edit environment variable `PATH` for your Windows to move `c:\cygwin\bin` to the left of `C:\Windows\system32`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I already know this. The problem is when I must specify a tab character for sorting tabbed files by second colun.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (in Windows a tab is '^t' rather than '\t'):

```
sort -t'^t' -k2 file.txt
```