# Sort Tab-Deliminated File with Variable Words and Spaces

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, csv

I have a file with lines that all begin with a date, followed by a tab, followed by a random number of words and spaces—some of which include numbers. For example:

```
    20140217    iPhone Upgrade Available
    20131101    Job Application Due
    20131219    Renew or return all library books
    20131114    Pay cell phone bill
```

I'm trying to sort this file by the date string and only the date string.

As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter), I've tried all kinds of combinations of sort -t$'\t' and -k1, but I keep getting garbled results.

Any help would be much appreciated. Also, it IS possible for me to replace that tab with a space or another character, if that would help for any reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to try

```
sort -n -k1,1 file
```

output is

```
20131101    Job Application Due
20131114    Pay cell phone bill
20131219    Renew or return all library books
20140217    iPhone Upgrade Available
```

Comment: For the actual example I recently provided above, this is what that yields, on a single line: 20131114 Pay cell phone bill library books

Comment: The output you gave is exactly what I want, but for whatever reason that is still not working for me in OSX Terminal while outputting the results to a new file. I'm getting a file that is the same as my input, using this command `sort -n -k1,1 /Users/Username/Desktop/input.txt > /Users/Username/Desktop/output.txt`

Comment: so is your terminal `xterm`? I think you can run `xterm` on `OS X` right?

Comment: Okay—the problem had something do to with the way the lines were broken in my files. This is working for me now. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else having this problem or wondering: Because the file was being generated with Applescript, it was creating Classic Mac (CR) linebreaks instead of Unix (LF) ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
sort -k1,1 file
```

Comment: I intentionally didn't use `-n` since OP wanted to use only date part to sort and date part is always 8 digit.