# How can I sort a 10GB file?

Tags: linux, sorting, large-files

I'm trying to sort a big table stored in a file. The format of the file is
(ID, intValue)

The data is sorted by `ID`, but what I need is to sort the data using the `intValue`, in  descending order.

For example

```
ID  | IntValue
1   | 3
2   | 24
3   | 44
4   | 2
```

to this table

```
ID  | IntValue
3   | 44
2   | 24
1   | 3
4   | 2
```

How can I use the Linux `sort` command to do the operation? Or do you recommend another way?

Comment: `sort -k`? read `man sort` for how to define the key

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix Sort with Tab Delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037365/unix-sort-with-tab-delimiter)

Answer (score 30):

> How can I use the Linux sort command to do the operation? Or do you recommend another way?

As others have already pointed out, see `man sort` for `-k` & `-t` command line options on how to sort by some specific element in the string.

Now, the `sort` also has facility to help sort huge files which potentially don't fit into the RAM. Namely the `-m` command line option, which allows to merge already sorted files into one. (See [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for the concept.) The overall process is fairly straight forward:

1. Split the big file into small chunks. Use for example the `split` tool with the `-l` option. E.g.:

   `split -l 1000000 huge-file small-chunk`
2. Sort the smaller files. E.g.

   `for X in small-chunk*; do sort -t'|' -k2 -nr < $X > sorted-$X; done`
3. Merge the sorted smaller files. E.g.

   `sort -t'|' -k2 -nr -m sorted-small-chunk* > sorted-huge-file`
4. Clean-up: `rm small-chunk* sorted-small-chunk*`

The only thing you have to take special care about is the column header.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
sort -t' ' -k2 -nr < test.txt
```

where test.txt

```
$ cat test.txt 
1  3
2  24
3  44
4  2
```

gives sorting in descending order (option -r)

```
$ sort -t' ' -k2 -nr < test.txt 
3  44
2  24
1  3
4  2
```

while this sorts in ascending order (without option -r)

```
$ sort -t' ' -k2 -n < test.txt 
4  2
1  3
2  24
3  44
```

in case you have duplicates

```
$ cat test.txt 
1  3
2  24
3  44
4  2
4  2
```

use the uniq command like this

```
$ sort -t' ' -k2 -n < test.txt | uniq 
4  2
1  3
2  24
3  44
```